# Bizarre SQL SRS error when trying to access SCCM reporting reports

Tags: sql-server, sccm, ssrs

In case this is an X-Y problem, what I'm trying to do is grab logs from SQL Server Reporting Services to tell me who did a couple horrible things in our SCCM environment - 1) deploying a rather large and complex install package to the All Systems collection and 2) replacing all my curated and properly defined collections (using query tasks) with a bunch of horrible direct-membership rules collections that cover about half our SCCM-managed systems.  If there's a better way than the [SSRS-backed reports under the monitoring section of the SCCM console](https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/who-created-that-deployment/), I'd be happy to hear it.

Anyhow, after a frustratingly long series of attempts to access the SCCM reports from more convenient computers, I sucked it up, logged onto the SQL server running SSRS, disabled IE enhanced security, and tried to hit up the report in question, where I was greeted with the below error:

[image: SSRS Error]

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

This seems to possibly indicate that the computer I'm doing this from doesn't trust the server running SSRS, but that makes no sense, given that I'm trying to access this report from the SQL server running SSRS.

In case the versioning matters, all the servers involved in this are running Server 2012 R2, we're running SCCM 1802 and SQL Server 2012 (11.0...), Enterprise edition, in a Windows Server Failover Cluster to allow us to run the databases that support it in database availability groups.

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be the issue, or even where to look to narrow this down?